# Удаление из файла элемента словаря (Python)

Tags: python

Пытаюсь сделать адресную книгу по книге Byte of Python.

Пытаюсь удалить контакт из файла:

```
def delete_person(self):
    f = open('mybook.txt', 'ab+')
    allcontacts = pickle.load(f)
    deluser = input('Введите имя того, кого хотите удалить?')
    del allcontacts[deluser]
    f = allcontacts
    pickle.dump(PhoneBook.mybook, f)
    f.close()
```

В чем может быть проблемка? Пробовал вставлять разные режимы чтения и записи в файл.

Выдает ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/PythonWork/Kate/phonebookclassi.py", line 81, in <module>
phonebook.delete_person()
File "C:/PythonWork/Kate/phonebookclassi.py", line 36, in delete_person
allcontacts = pickle.load(f)
EOFError: Ran out of input
```

Comment: Попробуйте открывать файл в режиме чтения `'rb'`.

Comment: Так мне надо и прочитать, и потом записать (то есть словарь залить в файл с удаленным элементом)

Comment: Открываете файл, считываете словарь, закрываете файл, удаляете элемент словаря, открываете файл (в режиме записи), записываете словарь, закрываете файл. `Pickle`, вроде бы, не поддерживает ничего, кроме `wb`/`rb`.

Answer (score 1):

Можно только читать или писать. Не одновременно. Если вы суете в файл несколько pickle объектов, то нужно их потом оттуда последовательно читать, пока не будет достигнут конец файла. Как-то так:

```py
import pickle

obj1 = {"foo": "bar"}
obj2 = {"eggs": "spam"}
obj3 = {"blah": "blah"}

with open("dump.pkl", "a+b") as f:
    pickle.dump(obj1, f)
    pickle.dump(obj2, f)
    pickle.dump(obj3, f)

with open("dump.pkl", "rb") as file:

    objects = []
    while True:
        try:
            objects.append(pickle.load(file))
        except EOFError:
            break
print(objects)

>>> [{'foo': 'bar'}, {'eggs': 'spam'}, {'blah': 'blah'}]
```

А `Ran out of input` возникает в случае, если файл пуст или поврежден.